# Cyclic dependency between 2 Xcode targets

Tags: xcode, macos, compiler-errors

I've encountered the following compilation issue once compiling Xcode project that include both targets : `myApp` and `libmylib`

Perhaps anyone can explain how does those 2 targets have cross dependency according to the logs below ?

```
Cycle in dependencies between targets 'myApp' and 'libmylib'; building could produce unreliable results. This usually can be resolved by moving the target's Headers build phase before Compile Sources. 
Cycle path: myApp → libmylib → myApp
Cycle details:
→ Target 'myApp' has copy command from '/path/to/myapp/project/DerivedData/osx/Build/Products/Debug/liblibmylib.dylib' to '/path/to/myapp/project/DerivedData/osx/Build/Products/Debug/myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/liblibmylib.dylib'

→ Target 'libmylib' has link command with output '/path/to/myapp/project/DerivedData/osx/Build/Products/Debug/liblibmylib.dylib'
○ Target 'libmylib' has copy command from '/path/to/myapp/project/libmylib-1.3.0-darwin-x86_64/lib/libcbor.0.5.0.dylib' to '/path/to/myapp/project/DerivedData/osx/Build/Products/Debug/libcbor.0.5.0.dylib'
○ Target 'libmylib' has link command with output '/path/to/myapp/project/DerivedData/osx/Build/Products/Debug/liblibmylib.dylib'
```

thanks !